# How to create a Next and Preview button using JQuery? (image gallery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, gallery

the fiddle so far:

jsfiddle.net/hYEzV/993/

So I'm looking for a button that can change to the next image or the preview image etc 
Im not sure how to go about it tho...

I've created both previous and next button already in the fiddle they just need the function to change to the next or previous image.

Thanks to anyone who can help and explain 
thank you.

edit: I'm looking for it to still autoplay like it is doing im just after the ability to flick through the images instead of waiting for the timer if the person didn't want to just sit and wait and watch. I also need the link button in the bottom right to be there as it is.

For the next button I was think this:

```
$("#Stage_Next_Div_Button").click(function(){
  $(function(){

     $("#container img").first().appendTo('#container').fadeOut(1000);
    $("#container img").first().fadeIn(1000);
});
});
```

But No idea of how to do the Previous button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hYEzV/998/

I removed the timer and added the click events to the arrow elements.
The `test()` function was doing the next action correctly, I reverted the images for the `prev()` function.

The `<a>` elements are not relevant, you could get rid of them.

Comment: I'm looking for it to still autoplay like it is doing im just after the ability to flick through the images instead of waiting for the timer if the person didn't want to just sit and wait and watch. I also need the link button in the bottom right to be there as it is. my apologies for not being clear, everything I need is there I just need the ability to flick threw the images added...But how you have it working is what I'm looking for with the next and previous function but Still autoplaying and with the link at bottom right autoplaying with the images like in my fiddle...

Comment: I edited the jsfiddler, but that really was an easy one. You just have to put the setTimeout back as it was.

Answer (score 1):

I'd not discuss why you decided to write your slider in that some weird way.
This is not the best method to do things like this, but yea... it works.

I sticked to your code and made two functions, next() and prev().

Just bind click event to your buttons and fire next() or prev() function.

```
$("#Stage_Next_Div_Button").click(function() {
    next();
});

$("#Stage_Previous_Div_Button").click(function() {
    prev();
});

function prev() {
    $("#Link a").last().prependTo('#Link').fadeIn(1000);
    $("#Link a").first().next().fadeOut(1000);

    $("#container img").last().prependTo('#container').fadeIn(1000);
    $("#container img").first().next().fadeOut(1000);
}

function next() {
    $("#Link a").first().appendTo('#Link').fadeOut(1000);
    $("#Link a").first().fadeIn(1000);

    $("#container img").first().appendTo('#container').fadeOut(1000);
    $("#container img").first().fadeIn(1000);
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hYEzV/995/

Docs:

- click - http://jqapi.com/#p=click
- prependTo - http://jqapi.com/#p=prependTo
- appendTo - http://jqapi.com/#p=appendTo

Comment: Thanks, I need that exact next and previous function but for the gallery to still "autoplay" by itself, I've updated my Question explaining it all a little bit better, my apologies!